# Error from javascript file but not console?

Tags: javascript, client-object-model

The error in question

> Uncaught Error: The property or field has not been initialized.
>   It has not been requested or the request has not been executed.
>   It may need to be explicitly requested.

Here is the code, just trying to get a simple count of a list.

```
var CustomAction = function(){
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = clientContext.get_web(); 
    this.oList = web.get_lists().getByTitle("Classification");

    // .load() tells CSOM to load the properties of this object
    // multiple .load()s can be stacked
    clientContext.load(oList);

    // now start the asynchronous call and perform all commands
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFailure));

    // method will exit here and onSuccess or OnFail will be called asynchronously
};

function onSuccess(sender, args) {
    alert('No of rows: ' + oList.get_itemCount());
};

function onFail(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed.\n' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
};
```

The error occurs at  `oList.get_itemCount()`. What reason would there be for this to be happening? I tried using `$( document).ready` and `$(window).onload` but the problem still occurs.

So like I said, it works when I copy/paste that into the browser but running it from file it doesn't.

Comment: Try changing `clientContext.load(oList);` to `clientContext.load(this.oList);`

Comment: @AmalHashim I'd try `clientContext.load(sender.oList)`;

Comment: Nope still same problem. Could it be because of how I call `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(CustomAction, "sp.js");`? There seems to be many different sp files running in the background.

http://i.imgur.com/rZjFAge.png

Comment: Weird, it works when I use your code in IE dev tools.  We can tell by the error that the JSOM library is loaded, so I don't think it's the way you're calling the function.  I can only think of two things: 1) Try `clientContext.load(oList, "Include(ItemCount)");` instead (not 100% sure that'll work). 2) Double check that no other code is using `oList`.  There's a chance that something else is overwriting the variable after your async function is called, thus causing it to be uninitialized.  Though the `this.oList` should prevent that from being the case.

Comment: On a second note, must you use JSOM, or can you use REST?  The endpoint for getting the item count would be `<siteUrl>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Classification')/itemcount`.

Comment: I could do that too, how would I go about doing it though? Sorry if that's an obvious answer.

Comment: Your code should work, but I'll just note this: No need to use `new` keyword when you call `get_current()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some scoping problems...

When you say `clientContext.load(oList);`

The `oList` that you're referring to is different than the variable you set above using the 'this' keyword.

Either use `this.oList` throughout every call (this will work on the success and fail methods because of `Function.createDelegate`) or change the first `this.oList` to `var oList = ...` -- which will also still work in the success and fail methods because of `Function.createDelegate`

Here is my attempt at a fairly straight-forward re-factor:

```
    // note: I changed the function name -- js convention is Proper case for Constructors only
var customAction = function() {
        var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var web = clientContext.get_web();
        var oList = web.get_lists().getByTitle("Classification");

        // .load() tells CSOM to load the properties of this object
        // multiple .load()s can be stacked
        clientContext.load(oList);

        // now start the asynchronous call and perform all commands
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onFail);

        function onSuccess(sender, args) {
            alert('No of rows: ' + oList.get_itemCount());
        }

        function onFail(sender, args) {
            alert('Request failed.\n' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        }
    };
```

The handlers are defined inside of the calling function, which allows you to forego mucking around with 'createDelegate' or 'this'

Comment: Thank you for this. The problem I was actually having was that I was including `sp.js` inside the script which is why it worked in console but not the file. It must have caused wonkyiness problems with `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', CustomAction);
```

Comment: Nope, no good either :/. I appreciate the help you are giving though.

Answer (score 0):

To do this with REST, you can do the following:

```
var CustomAction = function(){
    var oDataUrl = hostUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Classification')/ItemCount";
    $.ajax({
        url: oDataUrl,
        type: 'GET',
        headers: {
            accept: 'application/json;odata=nometadata',
            content-type: 'application/json;odata=nometadata'
        },
        success: onSuccess,
        error: onFail
    });

    function onSuccess(data) {
        alert('No of rows: ' + data.value);
    }

    function onFail(data, errCode, errMessage) {
        alert('Request failed.\n' +  errMessage);
    }
};
```